# one to many save, codeigniter DataMapper

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

Working on a site where a user can add videos.  Each video can be in many sections.  It can also have many questions.  Video has a one-to-many relationships with both the question and section classes.

I'm getting the section and video classes like this:

```
    $s = new Section();
    $s->where('section', $this->post->section)->get();
```

then saving like this:

```
    $v->save($u, $s, $q);
```

where $v is a video object, $u is a user object and $q is a question object.

I want to allow the user to POST multiple questions and sections.  How do I save those relationships.  Should $s and $q be arrays of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure that I understand what you mean but yes yu can save multiple relations at the same time.

Like this:

```
$s = new Section();
$s->where_in('section', $array_with_sections_ids)->get();

$v->save(array($u, $s->all, $q));
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was exactly what I was looking for.  Don't know how I missed it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You use different tables in your database. Like Video, Question and VideoQuestion where you store the video ID with the different Question id's

Then VideoExample would look like:

```
| video_id | question_id |
--------------------------
|    1     |      1      |
|    1     |      5      |
...
```

for inserting this data, first insert the video and get its ID with

```
$videoId = $this->db->insert_id()
```

Do the same for your question and you've got your ID's ;)
The same for the other tables and you're done. Good Luck!

Comment: I've already got all my relational tables set up, and single saves work just fine.  I can save a relation between a video and section, for example.  What I need to do is save a relationship between a video and an arbitrary number of sections.  Is there a quick way to do that, or do I have to just loop through $_POST['sections'] and save a relationship each time?  Sorry if my question was unclear.